# Can't archive on Xcode: CocoaPods linking error

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

On an iOS project, when I compile my project to run it, it works fine.
But if I archive it, it fails with the following error:

```
ld: file not found: /Users/xxxxx/Work/xxxxx/codes/xxxxx/DerivedData/xxxxx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/xxxxx/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/libPods.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using Xcode 4.6 and iOS 5.0.

Comment: And does the file `..../libPods.a` exist?

Comment: Not in the InstallationBUildProductsLocation folder and I have no idea how to get it compile there.

Comment: Seems there is a dependency on the Xcode name, I get errors that '/Applications/Xcode46-DP4.app/Contents/Developer' does not exist, well, I have 4.6 release so that is wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I searched for a long time and finally got something and solved the same problem for me. For anyone who still needs:

In *Build Setting* > *Other Linker Flag*:

Probably the flag is different for Debug and others.
Try to change wherever `$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)` to `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)`.

For me, I changed `$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)/libPods.a` to `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libPods.a`, and problem solved.