# Can't archive after migrating to CocoaPods

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods, localytics

We have recently migrated to CocoaPods to make dependencies simpler. It worked very well until today when we tried to archive it for crashlytics. I am using `Xcode 6`.

I keep getting `ld: library not found for -lsqlite3`

This is how I have set my Podfile

```
platform :ios, "7.0"
platform :ios, :deployment_target => '7.0'
target "F11i" do
pod 'NSData+Base64', '~> 1.0'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.18'
pod 'CrashlyticsFramework', '~> 2.2'
pod 'Localytics-AMP', '~> 2.60'
end

target "F11iTests" do
pod 'NSData+Base64', '~> 1.0'
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.18'
pod 'CrashlyticsFramework', '~> 2.2'
pod 'Localytics-AMP', '~> 2.60'
end
```

After running pod install, this is what I see:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Bolts (1.1.2)
Using CrashlyticsFramework (2.2.4)
Using Facebook-iOS-SDK (3.18.0)
Using Localytics-AMP (2.60.0)
Using NSData+Base64 (1.0.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

I am opening the project via `xcworkspace`

I tried the solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14644122/cant-archive-on-xcode-cocoapods-linking-error), but I dont see any `$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)` in first place in the suggested solution.

[image]

Any advice please?

**UPDATE**
`LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS` looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What is your `LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS`? Where is sqlite3.a located on your system?

Comment: Please see updated question for new screenshot.  I thought cocoapods would take care of all dependencies for me? Do I have to add sqllite3.a manually to the `frameworks`?

Comment: That is very odd, I have `libsqlite3.dylib` in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib`.

Comment: By the way can you build for a device or does it only work in the simulator? Can you build for the simulator in Release?

Comment: Just checked the same directory. I don't that `libsqlite3.dylib` in there. It works fine in simulator. But I can't deploy via cable to my iPad either. Same error. :(

Comment: I see, I would guess that you do have `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.0.sdk/usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib`

Comment: Yes indeed! I do have that. So what is the verdict? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following our comment chain, you have a bad install of Xcode.

The Platform SDK for devices is missing at least 1 file that is in the Platform SDK for the simulator. Who knows what else is wrong.

My suggestion is delete Xcode and do a fresh install from Apple.

Comment: +1, I can't thank you enough.  I uninstalled and reinstalled XCode as you said and it works now.  It was very hard to figure that out.